# How to get value of an HTML input element?

Tags: javascript

I have a form with 2 input elements and I want to get value with i. But the value is nan.

```js
let inputN1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_number1").value)
let inputN2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_number2").value)
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="input_number1" style="margin-left:430px">
  <input type="text" id="input_number2">
</form>
```

Comment: When does your parseInt run? When the user entered some actual values in the fields?

Comment: At the time your code runs, the `input` elements do not have a value. You most likely need to run the code under the `submit` event of the `form` or `input` event of the `input` elements instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you first have to enter values into the text fields before trying to read/print the values. This one works as expected:

```js
function printValues() {
  let inputN1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_number1").value);
  let inputN2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_number2").value);
  console.log("inputN1: " + inputN1);
  console.log("inputN2: " + inputN2);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="input_number1">
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="input_number2">
</form>

<button onclick="printValues()">Print values</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the input elements are not rendered yet so you need to make function to execute when the elements are rendered

```js
function getvalue() {
  let inputN1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_number1").value);
  console.log("inputN1: " + inputN1);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="input_number1">
<button onclick="getvalue()">Print values</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read the value of an empty element it will be an empty string. If you try to parse the empty string it will lead to NAN.

You can get the value after submitting the form or by listening to the input fields.

```
let inputN1 = document.getElementById("input_number1")
inputN1.addEventListener("input", (ev) => {
    console.log(ev.target.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a button or else it will come out NaN.

Here is the javascript:

```js
document.getElementById("submit").onclick  = function() {
  let inputN1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_number1").value)
  let inputN2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input_number2").value)
}
```

And here is the form you have with the button:

```html
<form id="myForm">
 <input type="text" id="input_number1" style="margin-left:430px">
 <input type="text" id="input_number2">
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

parseInt() function returns Nan or integer value. So in your case when you enter a string it try to convert it into integer but failed and return NAN. If you want to get number input, only change the type and remove parseInt;

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are using `parseInt()`.

The value of the input is an empty string `""` when you are getting its value and the function `parseInt()` converts the empty string to `NaN`